# Azure Service Fabric - more than one service instance per node

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have Azure Service Fabric stateless service which doesn't use any endpoints. It takes message from queue, processing it and save results to db.

I want to deploy 10 instances on my 2 nodes. By default I have -1 instancecount - it means that there will be 2 instances for 2 nodes. I can specify instancecount as 1 or 2 and it will be OK, but I cannot set 10 instances, it gives me error.

So I decide to create another instance of my application type. Is it right solution? Is there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: As answered by LoekD, you cannot have more than one instance on same node because of some SF constraints that blocks it, to make your service more reliable in cases where the entire node fails, but the point of the issue I have opened a while ago here (https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/325) it shouldn't in cases where we have multiple instances spread across multiple nodes. If you go through the answers in the issue, you will find ways to workaround it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can currently choose from:

1. Multiple Application instances (as you're doing). Multiple Applications hosting a service. Increases complexity, because instances must be managed.
2. Multiple Services. One application, hosting multiple services. Same downside as #1.
3. Multiple Partitions within a service (instead of one `SingletonPartition`). Downside of this, is that this number is 'fixed'. Changes require redeployment of the type with some downtime.
4. Use [multiple receivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#scenarios) inside one service. Probably a good option, because it gives the least overhead, as creating multiple processes (#1, 2 & 3) creates some overhead.

(an important question is: do you really require multiple instances?)

More info [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/325).

Answer (score 1):

This new feature is available in service fabric now for stateless service, more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-advanced-placement-rules-placement-policies#placement-of-multiple-stateless-instances-of-a-partition-on-single-node)

> **Placement of multiple stateless instances of a partition on single**
> **node**
>
> The AllowMultipleStatelessInstancesOnNode placement policy allows
> placement of multiple stateless instances of a partition on a single
> node. By default, multiple instances of a single partition cannot be
> placed on a node. Even with a -1 service, it is not possible to scale
> the number of instances beyond the number of nodes in the cluster, for
> a given named service. This placement policy removes this restriction
> and allows InstanceCount to be specified higher than node count.